# Is it possible to display error message along with FilteringTextInputFormatter on Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I have implemented TextField with FilteringTextInputFormatter as below to allow enter only alphanumeric characters. But at the same time I want to display error message if user tap on a denied character. Is is possible with FilteringTextInputFormatter?
I know its possible to just display error message with a simple regex validation, But I want both FilteringTextInputFormatter and error message together.

`static final _alphaNumericCharacters = RegExp('[0-9a-zA-Z]');`

```
TextField(
      controller: _myController,
      onChanged: provider.onChanged,
      decoration: InputDecorations.buildErrorInputDecoration(
          hintText:
              'Please enter your ID',
          setError: isInputError,
          errorText:
              'Only alphanumeric characters are allowed'),
      keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
      inputFormatters: <TextInputFormatter>[
        FilteringTextInputFormatter.allow(_alphaNumericCharacters),
      ],
    ),
```

Answer (score 1):

You can custom `TextInputFormatter` like this

```
class Decimal extends TextInputFormatter {
  final Function(bool) onError;
  Decimal({this.onError});

  @override
  TextEditingValue formatEditUpdate(TextEditingValue oldValue, TextEditingValue newValue) {
    // allow only one of common decimal separator
    bool match = RegExp(r'^[0-9]+([.,])+[0-9]+$').hasMatch(newValue.text);
    onError(match);
    return newValue;
  }
}
```

Your text input should look like:

```
TextField(
  ...
  errorText: _isError ? 'error' : null,
  inputFormatters: [
    Decimal(
      onError: (match){
        setState((){
          // if not match, error is true, otherwise
          _isError= !match; 
        }); 
      }),
  ],
)
```

Worked in my case, only allow for valid decimal format. You can give it a try to custom for your own `TextInputFormatter`.

Answer (score 0):

Define a bool value for checking input value.

```
bool checkDigit = true;
```

In TextFormField,

```
TextFormField(
  decoration: InputDecoration(
    errorText: checkDigit == false
                 ? "You can write only numeric values"
                 : ""),
  keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
  onChanged: (value) {
    if (!_isNumeric(value)) {
      setState(() {
        checkDigit = false;
      });
    } else {
       setState(() {
         checkDigit = true;
       });
    }
   },
   inputFormatters: <TextInputFormatter>[
     FilteringTextInputFormatter.allow(_alphaNumericCharacters),
   ],
  ),
```

isNumeric function detects parameter is a number or not. If the given value is number, return true otherwise false.

```
bool _isNumeric(String result) {
  return double.tryParse(result) != null;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the input, but this will work only for numeric values. But my requirement is Alphanumeric.